# Views in collapsibleToolbar not showing up

Tags: android, android-coordinatorlayout, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

I am new to android, I am trying to create a profile page for a test app. I would like the profile details part to scroll up leaving just a tab view on scroll. The problem is the textView profile_username and profile_goals do not display text even when hard coded. They are only visible when i put profile_details into the scroll view. Does this have anything to do with the behavior of collapsibleToolbars?

```html
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="nonso.android.nonso.ui.fragments.ProfileFragment"
    >

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/my_appbar_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/profile_collapsing_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
        app:contentScrim="@color/colorPrimary">
        <FrameLayout
                android:id="@+id/profile_details"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

                <FrameLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="100dp">
                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/profile_banner_image"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                        android:src="@drawable/balloon_background"/>
                </FrameLayout>
                <FrameLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
                    android:background="@color/white"
                    android:layout_gravity="bottom|center">

                    <RelativeLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent">

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/profile_username"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                            android:layout_marginStart="90dp"
                            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_5dp"
                            android:text="Username"
                            android:textSize="18sp"
                            android:textStyle="bold" />

                        <include
                            android:id="@+id/divider"
                            layout="@layout/divider_light"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_below="@id/profile_username"
                            android:layout_marginTop="20dp" />

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/profile_goals"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_below="@id/divider"
                            android:layout_margin="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
                            android:text="@string/profile_goals_temp" />

                    </RelativeLayout>
                </FrameLayout>
                <FrameLayout
                    android:id="@+id/profile_image_container"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="top|left">
                    <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
                        android:id="@+id/profile_image"
                        android:layout_width="72dp"
                        android:layout_height="72dp"
                        app:civ_border_color="@color/white"
                        app:civ_border_width="3dp"
                        android:src="@drawable/profile_image_placeholder"/>

                    <FrameLayout
                        android:id="@+id/profile_edit_profile_image"
                        android:layout_width="30dp"
                        android:layout_height="30dp"
                        android:background="@drawable/circular_view_fill"
                        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end">

                        <ImageView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="center"
                            android:scaleType="centerInside"
                            android:padding="5dp"
                            android:src="@drawable/ic_editor_light" />
                    </FrameLayout>

                </FrameLayout>
            </FrameLayout>
        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/profile_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/discover_search_btn"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/people"
                android:drawablePadding="@dimen/margin_10dp"
                android:textAllCaps="false"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_search_light"
                android:textSize="22sp"/>

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/btn_profile_settings"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="end"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_settings_light"
                android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/margin_5dp"/>
        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        >
        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/profile_tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:tabMode="fixed"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
            app:tabTextAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Widget.TabWidget"
            android:background="@drawable/grey_border_bottom_light"/>

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/profile_viewPager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@android:color/white" />
    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab_profile_create"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="end|bottom"
    android:layout_margin="16dp"
    android:color="@color/colorAccent"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_create_light"
    />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Any suggestions would be really appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: well then, looks like I had my background and text color the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well then, looks like I had my background and text color the same.